# To count words in file with grep or sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Here is test sample file--rime.txt.

[rime.txt](https://github.com/michaeljamesfitzgerald/Introducing-Regular-Expressions/blob/master/rime.txt)

1.to count all words in the file.

```
wc -w rime.txt
4081 rime.txt
awk 'BEGIN{num=0}{split($0, A);n=length(A);num=num+n;}END{print num}'  rime.txt
4081

grep -Ec  '\w' rime.txt
672
```

Why the total words is 672 with grep?
How to count it with sed?

2.to count words per line

```
awk '{split($0, A);print length(A)}'  rime.txt
```

How to do it with sed?

Comment: sed and arithmetic don't mix well... as per wc man page, `word is a non-zero-length sequence of characters delimited by white space` ... so equivalent would be `grep -io '[^ ]*' ip.txt` and count number of lines

Comment: grep -io '[^ ]*'  rime.txt |wc -l

Comment: yup, use wc or similar to count the lines... but why bother when `wc -w` is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grep is countig lines, not words, and you would never use sed for this because sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all.

Also, those awk scripts are ridiculous. The correct way to write the first one would be `awk '{num+=NF} END{print num+0}'` or with GNU awk `awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'END{print NR+0}'` and the second one is just `awk '{print NF}'`.

Comment: Why num+0 and NR+0?

Comment: So you get a number output even if the input file is empty. Try running the script on /dev/null with and without the `+0`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's only counting **lines not words**. From the man page:

> -c, --count
>                 Suppress  normal output; instead print a count of matching lines
>                 for each input file.  With the -v,  --invert-match  option  (see
>                 below), count non-matching lines.

And as you can see on the [link you provided](https://github.com/michaeljamesfitzgerald/Introducing-Regular-Expressions/blob/master/rime.txt), there are 834 lines and 672 SLOC ([Source lines of code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code)), and that last measurement is the one grep uses.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify your doubt on missing words take one small example here -

```
$cat ff
hello vipin
kumar
good night
```

Clearly, 3 lines with 5 words.

try with wc -w first-

```
$wc -w ff
5 ff
```

and the grep command that you have used -

```
$grep -Ec '\w' ff
3
```

In your case Total line count -

```
$wc -l < file.txt 
833
```

Total blank line count -

```
$grep '^$' file.txt |wc -l
161
```

Total non-blank line count -

```
$grep -v '^$' file.txt |wc -l
672
```

That is why you are seeing 672 lines.

```
$echo $(expr 833 - 161)
672
```

As expert has already mentioned that you shouldn't use sed for this operation and grep \w will give your the line count, not word count.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `grep` for the job, first form a regexp to resemble a word, I'll just use this: `[a-zA-Z'-]` and let your figure out a better one. Then use `grep -o` for matching:

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
```

And finally count the matches with `wc -l`:

```
$ grep -o [a-zA-Z'-] rime.txt | wc -l
4090
```

Comment: Am sure you meant to use `grep` over `count` in your answer :)

Comment: @Inian He asked how to use `grep`, obviously one can't count with it but can use it to extract the words to count outside of it. Then again, I just used `grep` to decrease my votes. :D